# ChartJS Line Chart Multi Color

Tags: php

[image]

Let's say I want to mark 8am and 9am points as Red color and the others as green. How do I do it?

`

```
echo '       
<div style="width:800px" >
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
  var xValues = ["'.$time.'"];
  var yValues = ['.$avgpercent.'];
  // var zValues = [22];
  var barColors = ["red"];
  
  new Chart("myChart", {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: xValues,
      datasets: [{
        label: "AvgPercent",
        backgroundColor: barColors,
        data: yValues,
        borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
        backgroundColor:"lightgreen"
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {display: true},
      plugins: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "'.$cpuname.' 24Hrs Report"
        }
    }
    }
  });
  </script>';
```

`

Above is the code I've used. $avgPercent has the percentage data(yvalues) and $time is the xvalues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 pointBackgroundColor: function(context) {
                    var index = context.dataIndex;
                    var value = context.dataset.data[index];
                    return value < 0 ? 'red' :  // draw negative values in red
                        index % 2 ? 'blue' :    // else, alternate values in blue and green
                            'green';
                }
```